# What's an optimal way of storing word metadata in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, database, kotlin, generics, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a data structure that would effectively store Slovak word metadata (gender, paradigm...). Normally, I would create just one `Word` class that would store `enum`s (`enum class`es) like `Gender`, or `Paradigm`. My problem is that not all the word types have the same properties (some words have a gender, some don't), and also, not all word types that have the same property name (like `Paradigm`) have the same values for the paradigm. This leaves me with one option: create a separate `class` for every word type (like `Noun`, `Adjective`...). This seems fine to me, but how would I go about creating a `Database class` and storing all the words in one database/data structure?

Comment: Pro tip: forget the word "optimal" when solving software problems. No single solution is ever optimal for all use cases. Every solution ever will have advantages and disadvantages. The trick is to balance out the disadvantages you can live with the easiest with the advantages you really need for *your specific use case*. Your question doesn't have nearly enough information for *us* to evaluate it, so you need to ask *way more specific* questions instead.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I'll try to explain it better next time and not use the word 'optimal'. Thanks.

Comment: Not just next time: update this question to include more details and/or ask a more specific question, because as it stands right now there  isn't really a good way to answer it.

Comment: Your enums could have a `NOT_APPLICABLE` element in them.

Comment: @Tenfour04 actually, that's not a bad idea. I'll try it out today. Thanks.

Comment: @Tenfour04 when I was thinking about it, I found out that this would not be very memory efficient. Because all the words would need to have all the properties. Even when they don't need them.

Comment: Yeah, it's a tradeoff. The other way to solve it is to have a separate table for each word type, represented by a unique class.